# rosserial non-unique executable

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed rosserial on Groovy with catkin and it works nicely, but when I enter

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

I get:

[rosrun] You have chosen a non-unique executable, please pick one of the following:

1. .../catkin_ws/install/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py
2. .../catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py

Why are there two and which one should I use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73636/rosserial-non-unique-executable/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are the same file -- just one is the installed version, and one is in the source tree (which is apparently still on your path). Is there a particular reason you are using "catkin_make install"?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-19**:
This page says to use catkin_make install

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

Specifically:

cd /src,

git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git,

cd ,

catkin_make,

catkin_make install,

source /install/setup.bash